# How can I get missing fields from json file in schema and vice versa

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have installed `jsonschema` using `pip install jsonschema`.

```
from jsonschema import validate

schema_data = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
        "additional" : {"type" : "number"},
        },
    }

json_data = {"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 34.99, "new": 90}
```

I am having above `schema_data` and `json_data` which is just validating the datatype.

Here `additional` is an extra field in `schema_data` which is absent in `json_data`, and `new` is present in `json_data`  which is absent in `schema_data`.

How can I list missing fields like *`additional` is missing in `json_data`* and *`new` is missing in `schema_data`*?

Comment: How familiar are you with JSON schema? Is your schema fixed, or are alterations to the schema okay?

Comment: What kind of alteration you are suggesting?

Comment: See my answer, you need to add more information to the schema to state what properties are required and if additional keys are allowed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Sure. I will check with various scenarios. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a JSON Schema, by default properties are not *required*, all that your schema does is state what type they must be *if the property is present*. So for validation to flag that `additional` is missing, you need to mark that key as [a required property](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties) first, by adding a `required` list with names:

```
schema_data = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
        "additional" : {"type" : "number"},
        },
    "required": ["price", "name", "additional"]
}
```

Now validation will fail your JSON data because `additional` is missing:

```
>>> validate(json_data, schema_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 541, in validate
    cls(schema, *args, **kwargs).validate(instance)
  File "/.../site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 130, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: 'additional' is a required property

Failed validating 'required' in schema:
    {'properties': {'additional': {'type': 'number'},
                    'name': {'type': 'string'},
                    'price': {'type': 'number'}},
     'required': ['price', 'name', 'additional'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'name': 'Eggs', 'new': 90, 'price': 34.99}
```

To make adding *more* keys invalid, you need to set `additionalProperties` to `false`; the default is to allow for extra properties:

```
schema_data = {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "price" : {"type" : "number"},
        "name" : {"type" : "string"},
        "additional" : {"type" : "number"},
        },
    "required": ["price", "name", "additional"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}
```

However, with `additional` still missing, the addition of `new` key isn't found when you use `validate()`, because the first error found is raised as an exception.

To get *all* schema validation errors, create a validator object for the schema then use the [`IValidator.iter_errors()` method](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.IValidator.iter_errors) to list all errors found:

```
from json_schema.validators import validator_for

validator = validator_for(schema_data)(schema_data)  # get class, create instance
for error in validator.iter_errors(json_data):
    print(error)
```

and now you get information about each error:

```
'additional' is a required property

Failed validating 'required' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'additional': {'type': 'number'},
                    'name': {'type': 'string'},
                    'price': {'type': 'number'}},
     'required': ['price', 'name', 'additional'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'name': 'Eggs', 'new': 90, 'price': 34.99}
Additional properties are not allowed ('new' was unexpected)

Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'additional': {'type': 'number'},
                    'name': {'type': 'string'},
                    'price': {'type': 'number'}},
     'required': ['price', 'name', 'additional'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance:
    {'name': 'Eggs', 'new': 90, 'price': 34.99}
```

Each `error` object in the loop is a [`ValidatorError` exception object](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors/#jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError), which has a series of attributes can help you figure out exactly what the problem is, in code.

Comment: How can I handle `required` properties for dict inside dict ?

Comment: Nested dictionaries are just more `”type”: “object”` schema entries. They can each have their own `required` list.

Comment: Hello, how can I only show which of my required properties are missing without showing the complete error message? Thank you

Comment: @DiegoMG : I guess, you can add try catch in that case.

Comment: @DiegoMG: If you are using my `validator.iter_errors()` example code then you can print the individual attributes of the `ValidatorError` exception object, instead of the whole object; e.g. `print(error.message)`. Follow the link in my answer for the API documentation for more options. If you are calling `validate()` directly, catch the `ValidatorError` exception and do the same with the caught exception instance.